# Optimizing MySQL Table Size With The Limit Option

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, optimization

If I understand how MySQL tables work, then each instance of the table consumes its full memory allotment, even if most the columns are blank. For instance, a blank TEXT column would consume 65536 bytes even if null. If only a few characters were later entered into this column, it would still consume the full 65536 bytes.

In a Rails migration, you can set a character limit on each column. For instance, you might limit that TEXT column to 500 characters. When doing this, do you also reduce the allotted memory for that column, so that instead of 65536 bytes, it consumes however many bytes are needed to represent 500 characters?

If I'm confident the column will always be limited to 500 characters, is it a common practice to limit it within the database or only within the model validations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For instance, a blank TEXT column would consume 65536 bytes even if null. If only a few characters were later entered into this column, it would still consume the full 65536 bytes.

Incorrect.  See [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/storage-requirements.html):

> #### Storage Requirements for String Types
>
> In the following table, ***`M`*** represents the declared column length in characters for nonbinary string types and bytes for binary string types. ***`L`*** represents the actual length in bytes of a given string value.
>
> ```
> +-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
> |          Data Type          |                 Storage Required                |
> +-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
> | CHAR(M)                     | M × w bytes, 0 <= M <= 255, where w is the      |
> |                             | number of bytes required for the maximum-length |
> |                             | character in the character set                  |
> +-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
> | BINARY(M)                   | M bytes, 0 <= M <= 255                          |
> +-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
> | VARCHAR(M), VARBINARY(M)    | L + 1 bytes if column values require 0 – 255    |
> |                             | bytes, L + 2 bytes if values may require more   |
> |                             | than 255 bytes                                  |
> +-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
> | TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT          | L + 1 bytes, where L < 28                        |
> +-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
> | BLOB, TEXT                  | L + 2 bytes, where L < 216                       |
> +-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
> | MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT      | L + 3 bytes, where L < 224                       |
> +-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
> | LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT          | L + 4 bytes, where L < 232                       |
> +-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
> | ENUM('value1','value2',...) | 1 or 2 bytes, depending on the number of        |
> |                             | enumeration values (65,535 values maximum)      |
> +-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
> | SET('value1','value2',...)  | 1, 2, 3, 4, or 8 bytes, depending on the number |
> |                             | of set members (64 members maximum)             |
> +-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
> ```